# azure pipeline yaml string value conversion

Tags: string, azure-pipelines

```
variables:
  - group: admin
  - name: project
    value: $[replace(lower($(Build.Repository.Name)), '.', '-')]
  - name: DOCKER_REPOSITORY
    value: foo.dkr.ecr.boo.amazonaws.com/$(project)
  - name: Version
    value: '1.0'
```

I couldn't make this replace/lower part work, what am I doing wrong? I tried 100 different combination

Build.Repository.Name : Foo.Boo.Hoo

(expected result) project : foo-boo-hoo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure DevOps variable resolution can be very tricky. You're in the right neighborhood, but missing some important distinctions.

You're combining different variable expansion syntaxes in one expression.

- `$()` is *macro* syntax. Variables with macro syntax get processed before a task executes during runtime.
- `$[]` is *runtime* syntax. Runtime expression syntax is expanded at runtime. Runtime expressions are designed to be used in the conditions of jobs, to support conditional execution of jobs, or whole stages.

[Ref: [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#understand-variable-syntax)]

When you access a variable within an expression, you can use `variables.variableName`. The exception is if the variable name itself has a `.` in it, in which case you should use `variables['variable.Name']`.

What you are actually looking for here is a **compile-time** expression: `${{ replace(lower(variables['Build.Repository.Name']), '.', '-') }}`

Comment: thanks, worked like a charm. first time fiddling around with this.